React state updates variable only when Chrome Inspect element is open
I've ran into a problem using React that there is a part of my code that only renders when the variable tipo assigned from useState gets a value. In my case the useState only updates the variable tipo if the inspect element from Chrome specifically is open.
import { Outlet, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Separator } from '@/components/ui/separator'
import { DMA } from '@/hooks/getDatePTBR'
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button'
import AlertDialogComponent from '@/components/alert-dialog-component.jsx'
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input"
import {
    Select,
    SelectContent,
    SelectItem,
    SelectTrigger,
    SelectValue,
} from "@/components/ui/select"

export default function CadastrarCliente() {
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        setError,
        formState: { errors, isSubmitting },
    } = useForm()

    const onSubmit = async (data) => { //recebe as informações do form
        try {
            if (tipo === "FISICA") {
                data.tipo = "FISICA";
                data.cnpj = null;
                data.razaosocial = null;
                data.responsavel = null;
            } else {
                data.tipo = "JURIDICA";
                data.cpf = null;
                data.rg = null;
            }
            console.log(data);
        } catch (err) {
            setError("root", {
                message: "Erro do backend",
            });
        }

    }

    const [tipo, setTipo] = useState(null);

    return (
        <>
            <div className='w-full m-6 mt-10' id='clientes'>
                <div className='grid grid-cols-2' id='clientes-header'>
                    <h3>Cadastrar cliente</h3>
                    <div className='justify-self-end'><DMA /></div>
                </div>

                <div className='mb-4 mt-2'><Separator /></div>

                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className='grid grid-cols-4 gap-4 items-start'>
                    <div>
                        <p>Tipo</p>
                        <Select>
                            <SelectTrigger>
                                <SelectValue placeholder="Selecionar" />
                            </SelectTrigger>
                            <SelectContent>
                                <SelectItem value="fisica" onClick={() => setTipo('FISICA')}>Física</SelectItem>
                                <SelectItem value="juridica" onClick={() => setTipo('JURIDICA')}>Jurídica</SelectItem>
                            </SelectContent>
                        </Select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>{tipo === 'FISICA' ? "Nome" : "Nome fantasia"} </p>
                        <Input {...register("nome", {
                            required: "Nome é obrigatório",
                            minLength: { value: 2, message: "Nome precisa ter pelo menos 2 caracteres." }
                        }
                        )} type='text'></Input>
                        {errors.nome && <div className='text-red-500 mt-2'>{errors.nome.message}</div>}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>Email</p>
                        <Input {...register("email")} type='email' autoComplete='email'></Input>
                        {errors.email && <div className='text-red-500 mt-2'>{errors.email.message}</div>}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>Celular</p>
                        <Input {...register("cel")} type='text'></Input>
                        {errors.cel && <div className='text-red-500 mt-2'>{errors.cel.message}</div>}
                    </div>

                    {tipo === 'FISICA' && <>
                        <div>
                            <p>CPF</p>
                            <Input {...register("cpf", {
                                required: "CPF é obrigatório",
                                minLength: { value: 11, message: "CPF precisa ter 11 caracteres." }
                            }
                            )} type='text'></Input>
                            {errors.cpf && <div className='text-red-500 mt-2'>{errors.cpf.message}</div>}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>RG</p>
                            <Input {...register("rg")} type='text'></Input>
                            {errors.rg && <div className='text-red-500 mt-2'>{errors.rg.message}</div>}
                        </div>
                    </>}
                    {tipo === 'JURIDICA' && <>
                        <div>
                            <p>CNPJ</p>
                            <Input {...register("cnpj", {
                                required: "CNPJ é obrigatório",
                                minLength: { value: 14, message: "CNPJ precisa ter 14 caracteres." }
                            }
                            )} type='text'></Input>
                            {errors.cnpj && <div className='text-red-500 mt-2'>{errors.cnpj.message}</div>}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>Razão social</p>
                            <Input {...register("razaosocial")} type='text'></Input>
                            {errors.razaosocial && <div className='text-red-500 mt-2'>{errors.razaosocial.message}</div>}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>Responsável</p>
                            <Input {...register("responsavel")} type='text'></Input>
                            {errors.responsavel && <div className='text-red-500 mt-2'>{errors.responsavel.message}</div>}
                        </div>
                    </>}
                    
                    <div>
                        <p>CEP</p>
                        <Input {...register("cep", {
                            minLength: { value: 8, message: "CEP precisa ter 8 caracteres." }
                        }
                        )} type='text'></Input>
                        {errors.cep && <div className='text-red-500 mt-2'>{errors.cep.message}</div>}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>Número</p>
                        <Input {...register("numero")} type='text'></Input>
                        {errors.numero && <div className='text-red-500 mt-2'>{errors.numero.message}</div>}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>Complemento</p>
                        <Input {...register("complemento")} type='text'></Input>
                        {errors.complemento && <div className='text-red-500 mt-2'>{errors.complemento.message}</div>}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>Bairro</p>
                        <Input {...register("bairro")} type='text'></Input>
                        {errors.bairro && <div className='text-red-500 mt-2'>{errors.bairro.message}</div>}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>Cidade/UF</p>
                        <Input {...register("cidade")} type='text'></Input>
                        {errors.cidade && <div className='text-red-500 mt-2'>{errors.cidade.message}</div>}
                    </div>
                    <p>{tipo}</p>
                    <div className='grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 col-span-2 self-end '>
                        <Link to='/dashboard/clientes/'>
                            <Button variant='outline' className='w-full' href='/dashboard/clientes/'>Voltar</Button>
                        </Link>

                        <Button disabled={isSubmitting} type='submit'>
                            {isSubmitting ? "Cadastrando..." : "Cadastrar"}
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                    
                    {errors.root && (
                        <AlertDialogComponent
                            tipo='warning'
                            title='Erro!'
                            desc={errors.root.message}
                            onClose={() => setError('root', null)}
                        />)}

                </form>
            </div>
            <Outlet />
        </>
    )
}

At the end I am rendering the tipo variable to see if it changes without opening the console and as expected, it only renders/change its value if I am with inspect element open on Chrome.
I tried using this page on Firefox but didn't work and I really don't know what else to do.

The code seems mostly fine to me. The only thing I'd suggest changing is moving the onSubmit handler declaration after the tipo state declaration. Think you could create a running CodeSandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

you recreated the double slit experiment in react!

I found the problem. It is with the ShadcnUI lib. The  element works in different ways that I don't have the explanation. But making a Button that changes the value "tipo" works normally.
